# react useEffect call twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express

i'm developing an api with express.js and for authentication system i used from jwt library and refresh and access token. everything work when i test my code with jest and supertest and test it with postman.

in front end i use react, and i save refresh token in cookie (httpOnly) and save user data such as access token, refresh token and username in memory with redux, everything works fine( route protection and etc. ).

when the user leaves the program, it is normal for the memory to be cleared( user information saved in redux will be deleted ) and when the user to the program returns to the login page.

but i have refresh token in cookie and i send post request with axios method with `withCredentials=true` to **/tokens** api for generate new access and refresh token, everything works fine and return new tokens and user data, and user does not redirect to authentication page.

**The problem**

i use react version 18.2.0, and i know when in useEffect in develop mode useEffect call twice,it's okay.
i send post request to `/tokens` api for generate new access and refresh tokens in useEffect.
according to the previous statement, this request is sent twice in development mode.

my logic in api, search user with refresh token that was sended with cookie and if find the user generate new tokens.

**but i'm noticed** somethimes in twice call, for the first api call ( /tokens ) find the user, but for the seccond call cannot find user and return **undefined**,
and sometimes both work successfully this is strange.

**here is my code**

react code:

```
    useEffect(() => {

    if (user === undefined) {
      axios.post('/tokens').then((result: any) => {

        dispatch(addUser(result.data.user));

      }).catch((error: any) => {
        dispatch(addUser(undefined))
      })
    }
  }, []);
```

backend code :

```
tokens = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response> => {

      
        const refreshToken = req.headers.cookie?.split('=')[1];

     
        const user: any[] = await this._userRepository.find({
            fields: [
                {
                    field: {
                        username: req.user.username,
                        email: req.user.email,
                        id: req.user.id,
                        refresh_token: refreshToken
                    },
                    op: 'AND'
                }
            ]
        });

   
        // in here sometimes find user and sometimes cannot find user with same data
        if (user[0] !== undefined) {

        
            const newAccessToken: string = generateJwt('access_token', user[0], '1m');

          
            const newRefreshToken: string = generateJwt('refresh_token', user[0], '10d');

       
            await this._userRepository.update({
                refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
            }, {
                fields: [
                    {
                        field: {
                            id: req.user.id,
                            username: req.user.username,
                            email: req.user.email,
                            refresh_token: refreshToken
                        },
                        op: 'AND'
                    }
                ]
            });

         
            const data: Record<string, any> = {
                status: true,
                message: 'New tokens generated successfully',
                user: {
                    access_token: newAccessToken,
                    refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
                }
            }

           

           
            return res.json(data)
        }

        // send error
        throw new BaseError('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
```

Comment: Please find your shift key and properly capitalize your sentences and your name (I). This isn't TikTok.

Answer (score 1):

This will happens in development mode of react. When a component is initially render then useEffect runs two time. This issue will not come when you serve the react build on production mode. There is one solution to stop twice calling of useEffect that you have to remove `React.Strict` from root file but this one is not recommended way.

Comment: yes i know that, but in server side cannot find user with same data in twice call why ?
first time find user, second time cannot find

Answer (score 0):

If we take your code from the front side as a base, I see that your `useEffect`  gives it its anonymous function but I notice that it will be executed every time, maybe it would be a good idea for this function to only be executed once, that is achieved by giving one or more variables to the array whose second parameter is the `useEffect` function, I would understand that you want it to be executed as long as the `user`  variable is modified, so if it is modified and remains undefined proceed to make the call via axios if not, does nothing.

```
useEffect(() => {

if (user === undefined) {
  axios.post('/tokens').then((result: any) => {

    dispatch(addUser(result.data.user));

  }).catch((error: any) => {
    dispatch(addUser(undefined))
  })
}
}, [user]);
```

Comment: An empty dependency array will only execute once, on mount, not on every render. If the dependency array argument is not provided at all, that is when it would be executed on every render.